# Aggregate query result is different on PHP from Mongo-cli

Tags: php, mongodb

I use mongodb with phpm and I want to use aggregate

this is my query directly in Mongo

```
db.getCollection('whitelist').aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {"whitelisted_email": false}
    },{
        $group:{
            _id:null,
            "users_id": {$addToSet:"$user_id"}
        }
    },{
        $project:{
            _id:0,
            "users_id":1
        }
    }
]
)
```

result

{
    "users_id" : [ 
        1.0, 
        2.0
    ]
}

In my php script my query is:

```
$users = $collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => ['whitelisted_email' => false]
                    ],
                    [
                        '$group' => [
                            '_id' => null,
                            'users_id' => ['$addToSet' => '$users_id']]
                    ],
                    [
                        '$project' => [
                            '_id' => 0,
                            'users_id' => 1,
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            );

foreach ($users as $user) {
                var_dump(json_encode($user->getArrayCopy(), true));
            }
```

my result is:
'{"users_id":[]}'

Why is the result different? The database is the same

[image]